# What is the probability of selecting the greedy action in a 0.5-greedy selection method for the 2-armed bandit problem?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, multi-armed-bandits, epsilon-greedy-policy

I'm new to reinforcement learning and I'm going through [Sutton and Barto](http://incompleteideas.net/book/the-book.html). Exercise 2.1 states the following:

> In $\varepsilon$-greedy action selection, for the case of two actions and $\varepsilon=0.5$, what is the probability that the greedy action is selected?

They describe the $\varepsilon$-greedy method on pages 27-28 as follows:

> ...behave greedily most of the time, but every once in a while,  say with small probability $\varepsilon$, instead select randomly from among all the actions with equal probability...

The above method makes the agent select an action randomly "every once in a while" from the action space uniformly with probability $\varepsilon$. I find the question imprecise since we don't know the "once in a while" in this exercise (i.e. is it once every $50$ timesteps? every time step?). If it's for every timestep, isn't it like a Bernouli problem where the parameter is $0.5$? I'd say that the agent has a $0.5$ chance to select a greedy action but I'm not sure at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I read section 2.2 of Sutton and Barto, and I understand your confusion: the $\epsilon$-greedy algorithm is not defined precisely on page 27-28. Selecting an action randomly "every once in awhile" with probability $\epsilon$ means selecting an action randomly with probability $\epsilon$ at each timestep and selecting an action greedily with probability $1-\epsilon$ at each timestep. This definition is standard and will be clear as you progress through the book and other relevant literature. For reference, the $\epsilon$-greedy algorithm is used in the pseudocode on page 32 of Sutton and Barto.

The key distinction in this problem is that it's asking for **the probability that the greedy action is selected, NOT the probability that an action is selected greedily**. Specifically, the greedy action can be selected when the agent selects an action randomly because the greedy action is in the action space and the *entire* action space is sampled uniformly when selecting an action randomly.

Since $\epsilon=0.5$, the agent will select an action greedily 50% of the time, which will 100% of the time be the greedy action. The agent will select an action randomly the other 50% of the time. Since there are two actions in the action space, the greedy action will be selected 50% of the time when the agent selects an action randomly. Therefore, the probability that the greedy action is selected at any single timestep is as follows:

\begin{align}
 &p(\mbox{greedy action}) \\
=\ &p(\mbox{greedy action AND greedy selection}) + p(\mbox{greedy action AND random selection})\\
=\ &p(\mbox{greedy selection}) \cdot p(\mbox{greedy action}\ |\ \mbox{greedy selection}) \\ 
&\hspace{1em}+ p(\mbox{random selection})\cdot p(\mbox{greedy action}\ |\ \mbox{random selection})\\
=\ &(1-\epsilon) \cdot p(\mbox{greedy action}\ |\ \mbox{greedy selection}) + \epsilon \cdot p(\mbox{greedy action}\ |\ \mbox{random selection})\\
=\ &0.5 \cdot p(\mbox{greedy action}\ |\ \mbox{greedy selection}) + 0.5 \cdot p(\mbox{greedy action}\ |\ \mbox{random selection})\\
=\ &0.5 \cdot 1 + 0.5 \cdot 0.5 \\ 
=\ &0.5+ 0.25 \\ 
=\ &0.75.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it's very clear and helpful. So the key difference that I've missed is between the action selection and the greedy selection. Thanks again !

Comment: could it be equal to $1$ if both actions yield the same reward, i.e. both actions are greedy?